# Whats the best way to identify a process?

Tags: c#, process

I need to track and interact with a Word process, and I've been finding/identifying the process by looking for all Word processes, and then executing code on each. Here's what I use:

```
 Process[] wordprocs = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
 foreach (var wordProc in wordprocs)
 { 
   blah blah blah
 }
```

Typically, only 1 Word process is running, so any suggestions of a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `var word = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").FirstOrDefault()` ??

Comment: How do you want to subsequently interact with it? `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")` can retrieve a COM automation interface to running instances of word via the ROT.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the option that multiple instances are running, just because that's the case 95% of the time - shouldn't you be looking for a way to identify a _specific_ instance, or is that your question in the first place?

Comment: Alex, I'm tracking Performance with Performance Counters.

Comment: C, you're right, and that's what actually made me do it this way originally, but since I've been using a controlled environment (VM), I haven't had any issues with multiple instances.

Comment: Jamiec, you're brilliant, and I'm an idiot. You suggested what I actually did first (found it in the comments), before deciding I should prepare for multiple instances.